# MySQL TIME() BETWEEN datetime issue

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find to which shift belongs a datetime field.

Shifts are defines as time, and I have a startingHour and endingHour.

The query

```
SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE TIME('2009-11-20 06:35:00') BETWEEN '06:00:00' and '19:00:00'
```

works perfect, but when the shift is set to start 19:00:00 to 06:00:00 and the time is 23:35:00 it doesn't return anything

```
WHERE TIME('2009-11-20 23:35:00') BETWEEN '19:00:00' and '06:00:00'
```

that line isn't returning anything though I do have records on the table

Thanks

[image] 
That's the shifts table.

if I query this:

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    b.Nombre
FROM turnos a
JOIN operarios b ON a.oID = b.oId
WHERE a.uId = 1
AND (TIME('2019-11-22 18:23:00') BETWEEN a.horaInicio AND a.horaFin )
LIMIT 1
```

I get the proper result, but when I query this:

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    b.Nombre
FROM turnos a
JOIN operarios b ON a.oID = b.oId
WHERE a.uId = 1
AND (TIME('2019-11-22 02:45:00') BETWEEN a.horaInicio AND a.horaFin )
LIMIT 1
```

I get no result.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: On a side note: a and b are bad alias names that make the query harder to read rather than easier. Use something like t for turnos and o for operarios instead.

Comment: `a between b and c` is short for `a >= b and a <= c`. Hence the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two cases: start time < end time and start time > end time. You need something like this:

```
where (start_time < end_time and $t >= start_time and $t < end_time)
or  (start_time >= end_time and ($t < start_time or $t >= end_time))
```

Comment: +10  i vastly prefer the **`>=`** and **`<`** comparison pattern for datetime, timestamp, time comparisons, vs. including equality on both sides of the comparison (like we get with `BETWEEN` operaator) which can lead to an overalap (where a value on the boundary will satisfy two distinct ranges). I much prefer to specify the range as the earliest time that is in the range as the lowerbound, and the earliest time that is outside the range. +10

Answer (score 0):

Since `'19:00:00'` is greater than `'06:00:00'` then:

```
BETWEEN '19:00:00' and '06:00:00'
```

returns `0` (`false`) and you get no rows.
One way to get the results that you want is to use `CASE` like this:

```
.................
AND 1 = CASE
  WHEN a.horaInicio <= a.horaFin THEN TIME('2019-11-22 02:45:00') BETWEEN a.horaInicio AND a.horaFin
  ELSE (TIME('2019-11-22 02:45:00') BETWEEN a.horaInicio AND '23:59:59') 
    OR (TIME('2019-11-22 02:45:00') BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND a.horaFin)  
END
```